# Vb.Net - Generate HTML table from results fetched through datareader

Tags: vb.net

I have written code in .net which fetches result from sql database

```
 _ExecutionResultsReader.Read()
{
//code
}
```

Based on results fetched from Datareader, I want to generate HTML table which then we will be sending in EMAIL.

How to dynmically generate this table code, as datareader will return diff columns and diff rows based on source query.

REgards

Comment: Use `for` loops and proper HTML escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You can just generate the table code. I'll put it to `StringBuilder`/`String` but the result can be written to `MemoryStream`/File instead.

```
Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
sb.Add("<table border='1'>")
While _ExecutionResultsReader.Read()
sb.Add("<tr>")
For Each fld As Object in _ExecutionResultsReader
  sb.Add("<td>" & fld & "</td>")
next
sb.Add("</tr>")
End While
sb.Add("</table>")
Dim Result as String=sb.ToString()
```

You can use more advanced customisation of the table with its attributes [HTML Tables](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) or CSS styles ([Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/html_tables))